# Laravel 5.4 - Missing Database Driver

Tags: sql-server, database

I am building a Laravel 5.4 app. It connects to 2 databases, mysql (default) and sql server which is readonly (via odbc).

Access to the sql server via the web routes is fine, however when using the api routes I receive a driver not found error message. Access and saving to and from the mysql db works in both web and api.

I am fairly new to Laravel, but I would like to know how to force all database drivers to be loaded in for the api, as per the web routes.

Comment: Do you have the ``pdo-odbc`` extension installed and enabled for your PHP? https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Comment: Yes. the pdo-odbc is installed and working, but only when I use the web routes. The api routes are the problem.